# Greater than float with awk

Tags: bash, macos, awk

I found some questions about this, but none of them really answered to my question.

I have a tabulated file like this:

```
2   10610   0   0   0   0.0105292
2   10649   0   0   0   0.041959
2   10682   0   0   0   0.0449746
2   10705   0   0   0   0.0441639
2   10797   2   0   0   0.0342728
2   10955   0   0   0   0.0136986
2   10957   0   0   0   0.0135135
2   11124   0   0   0   0.0583367
2   11336   1   0   0   0.0219502
```

and I used this command:

```
awk '{if ($6 > 0.4) print $6}' myfile
```

And here is the output:

```
0.0105292
0.041959
0.0449746
0.0441639
0.0342728
0.0136986
0.0135135
0.0583367
0.0219502
```

It's returning all the value for the 6th column. Here i should get no results since the condition is not respected. So I guess awk is not considering $6 as a float.

I tried other syntax but I still have the same problem.

I also tried the command on the first column and there it's working...

ps: I'm on MacOSX

**Edit:** Though it's working when I use awk '{print $6}'

Comment: your  `awk` might be broken.  try this `awk '$6+0>0.4{print $6}'`

Comment: Do you mean `0.4` or `0.04`?

Comment: You know your condition is never true, right? All the data in your 6th column are inferior to `0.4`. Maybe you meant `0.04` ? In this case your `awk` command [seems to work well](https://ideone.com/qfufwi)

Comment: I mean `0.4` , sorry this is not the entire file, it has more than 600k lines, but in some case the condition is true.
I tried karafka solution, but it's not working, so i tried to check to add 100 to all my values in $6 and i appears that awk print me "100" for all the lines with this command line : awk '{print $6+100}'

Comment: Then your input file isn't properly parsed, maybe because the columns are separated with weird characters. Could you check the output of `cat -A yourInputFile` (or `yourInputPipeline | cat -A`) to check for special characters? Spaces should just be represented as spaces, and tabulations should be represented as `^I` ; if you find anything else it might explain why `awk` finds your 6th column to be seemingly empty.

Comment: An example of how you might be fooled : [ideone](https://ideone.com/IJ02ND). This example might be realistic when copying data from a website (multiple consecutive spaces are normalized to a single one in HTML, so some CMS handle that by interleaving unbreakable spaces with the original spaces).

Comment: i tested cat -A, but this option doesn't exists for me. So from man i tried cat -v which should do the same : "-v      Display non-printing characters so they are visible.  Control characters print as `^X' for control-X; the
             delete character (octal 0177) prints as `^?'.  Non-ASCII characters (with the high bit set) are printed as
             `M-' (for meta) followed by the character for the low 7 bits."
but i don't get any special characters... still the same

Comment: i tried cat -vt file and i get this: '2^I10610^I0^I0^I0^I0.0105292
2^I10649^I0^I0^I0^I0.041959
2^I10682^I0^I0^I0^I0.0449746
2^I10705^I0^I0^I0^I0.0441639
2^I10797^I2^I0^I0^I0.0342728
2^I10955^I0^I0^I0^I0.0136986
2^I10957^I0^I0^I0^I0.0135135
2^I11124^I0^I0^I0^I0.0583367
2^I11336^I1^I0^I0^I0.0219502'

Comment: to Ed Morton, when i try print $6 it's working and it only print the 6th column...

Comment: i edited the question, i hope it's more clear. At first i wanted to print the whole line with $0, for me it's the same as getting $6. Here is the input and output first 10 lines

Comment: Thanks for fixing your question. The problems got to be your locale setting so try running it with the C locale specified: `LC_ALL=C awk '{if ($6 > 0.4) print $6}' myfile` and once you've verified that fixes it I'll add an answer with the reason why.

Comment: It worked ! after googling it i'm not sure to quite understand what's going on here, but it worked ! Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's your locale setting (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Locales and specifically https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Locale-influences-conversions), explicitly setting LC_ALL=C is one way to solve the problem:

```
LC_ALL=C awk '{if ($6 > 0.4) print $6}' myfile
```

What's happening is that you're trying to use a decimal point of `.` but your locale (typical in most European countries and many others) uses `,` instead. So when your input contains:

```
0.0105292
```

awk does not recognize it as looking like a number in your locale, so instead it gets treated as a string. If your input was instead:

```
0,0105292
```

THEN awk would recognize it as a number (so this is the other way to solve your problem - use commas as the decimal point in your input).

So to awk your code:

```
$6 > 0.4
```

is a string `"0.0105292"` being compared to a number `0.4` (per POSIX the `.` is **always** the decimal point when used in the code) and per this comparison table from the gawk manual:

```
        +----------------------------------------------
        |       STRING          NUMERIC         STRNUM
--------+----------------------------------------------
        |
STRING  |       string          string          string
        |
NUMERIC |       string          numeric         numeric
        |
STRNUM  |       string          numeric         numeric
--------+----------------------------------------------
```

we see that the type of comparison performed when a string is compared to a number (or anything else) is a string comparison.

So in your original code the string `"0.0105292"` is being string-compared with the number `0.4` and awk is apparently deciding that the former is greater than the latter (idk why, maybe some other locale effect).